# Weld - Asynchronous event observers

Tags: asynchronous, observer-pattern, jboss-weld

I am using Weld to observe events. I thought there was a way to specify if the observer was asynchronous or not, but I am not finding that annotation or documentation.

Can observers be asynchronous, if so, what do I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: I am thinking that the closest match I have is to use this:TransactionalObserverMethodImpl along with TransactionPhase.  If I specify a TransactionPhase other than during, the the notification is deferred in a runnable: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/event/TransactionPhase.html.

Comment: My only complaints with this is it is designed to run in a RequestContext.  Is that part of the specification?

Answer (score 5):

There is an open request for this: [CDI-31: Asynchronous events](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-31).

Depending on your requirements, you can, as indicated in your comment, set a different [transactional observer](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/events.html#d0e4075): If you use AFTER_COMPLETION or AFTER_SUCCESS, it should seem to your application like an asynchronous execution. However until a framework solves , I have just found an example using [JMS for asynchronous execution in CDI](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jjviana/archive/2010/04/13/decoupling-event-producers-and-consumers-jee6-using-cdi-and-jms).

Comment: It would be better if someoene opened a bug with the CDI expert group. Maybe we could get this into JEE7!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at post on [Piotr Nowicki's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920607/piotr-nowicki) blog http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/05/asynchronous-cdi-events/

He described a couple of methods for achieving asynchronous behavior of CDI events.

Answer (score 1):

If you guys want to see this happen, you'll need to head over the the link provided in Kariem's answer and voice your opinion. It seems the expert group is unwilling to consider adding async events because they consider it bloating the spec.

Honestly, Guice manages to offer this feature, and it remains lightweight, so I find the argument against this little counter-intuitive. Nevertheless, if you want to see this feature, head to the link, voice your opinion.

-Jonathan