# Fire CDI events asynchronously and wait till all consumers are finished

Tags: jsf, cdi

Is it possible to fire an event in a NamedBean asynchronously and to wait till all Consumers (Observers) are finished? The Consumer (Observers) should run asynchronously, but the event should be finished if all of them are finished.

e.g. I have 3 Beans (1 Bean which fires the event and 2 which observes the event).

Bean which fires the event:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class TestExecuter implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @MyEvent
    private Event<QueryTO> myEvent;

    public void run() {
        QueryTO queryTO = new QueryTO(null, null);

        FilterQualifier[] qualifiers = new FilterQualifier[3];
        qualifiers[0] = new FilterQualifier(TestA.FILTER_ID);
        qualifiers[1] = new FilterQualifier(TestB.FILTER_ID);

        System.out.println("Fire event");
        myEvent.select(qualifiers).fire(queryTO);
        //wait till observers are finished
        System.out.println("Event finished");
    }
}
```

Bean 1 which observes

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class TestA implements Serializable {
    public static final String FILTER_ID = "TestA";

    public void generateFilterQueryEvent(
            @Observes @Filter(FILTER_ID) @MyEvent QueryTO queryTo) {
        System.out.println("TestA called");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("TestA finished");
    }
}
```

Bean 2 which observes

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class TestB implements Serializable {
    public static final String FILTER_ID = "TestB";

    public void generateFilterQueryEvent(
            @Observes @Filter(FILTER_ID) @MyEvent QueryTO queryTo) {
        System.out.println("TestB called");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("TestB finished");
    }
}
```

Expected result: Both beans execute the code at the same time and after 3 seconds the event is finished and the event is finished. Currently it executes `TestA` and after that `TestB`, so I have to wait 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[AFAIK it's not supported by CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3791137/843804) although you can workaround it with an custom `AsyncEvent` class which gets the observers and calls them in separate threads. Here is a proof of concept example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod;
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class AsyncEvent<T> {

    private static final AnnotationLiteral<Any> ANY = 
        new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {
    };

    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public AsyncEvent() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        try {
            executorService.shutdown();
            final boolean terminated = executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (!terminated) {
                throw new RuntimeException("awaitTermination timeout");
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }

    public void fire(final T event) {
        fire(event, ANY);
    }

    public void fire(final T event, final Annotation... qualifiers) {
        final Set<ObserverMethod<? super T>> observers = beanManager.resolveObserverMethods(event, qualifiers);
        final Set<Callable<Void>> tasks = createCallablesForObservers(event, observers);
        invokeAll(tasks);
    }

    private Set<Callable<Void>> createCallablesForObservers(final T event, 
            final Set<ObserverMethod<? super T>> observers) {
        final Set<Callable<Void>> tasks = new HashSet<Callable<Void>>();
        for (final ObserverMethod<? super T> observer: observers) {
            final Callable<Void> callable = createCallable(event, observer);
            tasks.add(callable);
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    private Callable<Void> createCallable(final T event, 
            final ObserverMethod<? super T> observer) {
        final Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                observer.notify(event);
                return null;
            }
        };
        return callable;
    }

    private void invokeAll(final Set<Callable<Void>> tasks) {
        try {
            executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private static final AnnotationLiteral<Updated> UPDATED = new AnnotationLiteral<Updated>() {
};

@Inject
private AsyncEvent<Document> event;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Fire event");
    final Document document = new Document("test event");
    event.fire(document);
    event.fire(document, UPDATED);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx for your fast reply.
Where can I define the observers like i did it in  myEvent.select(qualifiers).fire(queryTO);

Comment: @Daniel: If I'm right you should change `ANY`. (You might also need an `InjectionPoint` in the `AsyncEvent` class.)

Comment: @Daniel: Check the update, please. I've added another `fire` implementation which supports qualifiers. (Unfortunately it does not support structures like `@Updated @Inject AsyncEvent`, I wasn't able to figure that out.)

Comment: Now it works fine. I can now set my qualifiers and only these Observers are called. 
If I add `@MySpecialEvent` to the injection point I get following error:
'No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]'
Example:

`@Inject`
`@MySpecialEvent`
`private AsyncEvent<QueryTO> event;`

and MySpecialEvent is:
`@Qualifier`
`@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })`
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`
`public @interface MySpecialEvent {`
`}`
Did you mean this that it doesn't work or was it sth. else?

Comment: @Daniel: I meant that.

Comment: Just a short enhancement. If you are using Java EE 7 you should use a managed executor service:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/injecting_an_executorservice_with_java